# SD card OS work environment useable on many machines

Tags: windows-10, sd-card, disk-encryption, liveusb, workspace

I am looking for a way set up an Windows 10 on an SD card, that I could use with different machines.

How I would like that to work:

- SD card and all the data is securely encrypted
- I plug it into a laptop, boot and securely work on my environment
- Everything is saved on the SD card, like it was a hard drive
- I plug it out, then move
- I plug it into another laptop, continue where left off

It would take all the data on the card to be encrypted when at rest.

I am not sure how to approach this (it is possible to install linux on a USB and work this way) with Windows 10. Any advice would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Windows 10 does not support booting from USB devices or SD Cards. You can *install* from USB stick or DVD, but that is a minimal environment usable only to install the OS. You can only boot from an IDE, SATA or NVMe device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As mentioned, this is *not* allowed for Windows 10. At one time, there was Windows-to-go, but Microsoft no longer support that.
2. Windows Recovery Environment (Win RE, previously "Windows PE") *can* be used to make bootable media, but by itself, it has almost no function. There are many variations on it, though, that have [slipstreamed](https://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/10-tools-for-creating-custom-windows-installation-discs-679477) additional software, such as [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/ultimate-boot-cd/). Note that many of these use older version of Windows, e.g., Windows 7.
3. Easiest and most functional might be to make a Live *Linux* USB or SD card, rather than Windows. [Ubuntu Live flash media with **persistence**](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) is, in essence, the entire Ubuntu OS, associated software including LibreOffice suite, Firefox browser and Thunderbird email client on a chip with 8 GB storage (actually, only 4 GB is for the OS and software, the other 4 or more GB is your "HDD"). *N.B.* Most flash memory is *slow* compared to a HDD, so you might consider using a small USB SSD, instead.

BTW, many PC's will *not* boot from their internal SD card reader; you may need to use an external card reader for that SD/XD card.